# How to use Endroid\QrCode on Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, qr-code, yii2-advanced-app

I have the following code, the library was installed through composer.

Model:

```
public function insertQR()
 {
        $this->qrCode = new QrCode();
        $this->qrCode
            ->setText($this->qr_text)
            ->setSize(300)
            ->setPadding(10)
            ->setErrorCorrection('high')
            ->setForegroundColor(['r' => 0, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'a' => 0])
            ->setBackgroundColor(['r' => 255, 'g' => 255, 'b' => 255, 'a' => 0])
            ->setLabel('Scan the code')
            ->setLabelFontSize(16)
            ->setImageType(QrCode::IMAGE_TYPE_PNG)
        ;

   }// end function
```

View:

```
<?php
// now we can directly output the qrcode
        header('Content-Type: '.$model->qrCode->getContentType());
        $model->qrCode->render();

?>
```

However at the moment of rendering the view I got the following raw png instead of the png: 
�PNG  IHDR@[V�J�!PLTE���������???���___���>�-� pHYs���+�IDATx����n�F�a�� ....

What could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You have to set header in controller not in view. otherwise yii will set it default html.

Comment: I have put: use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode; header('Content-Type:image/png');  on Controller, however I still get the raw png. What could be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the headers like this:

```
// At the top.
use yii\web\Response;

// In your function.
$response = Yii::$app->getResponse();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', $model->qrCode->getContentType());
$response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
$model->qrCode->render();
```

Yii2 requires the format of the response to be set to raw when returns an image response.

Comment: I did what you suggested, however I get a black screen with a white square on the middle of the browser. What could be missing? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like `$this->qr_text` is empty

Comment: No, $this->qr_text is returning a string. What could be wrong in the whole MVC pattern?

Comment: Don't know, the only way I could reproduce your exact situation was by passing an empty string.

Comment: I tried testing with: $this->qrCode->setText('THIS IS A TEST'). And I got the same output.

Comment: I have decided to use the library PHP QR Code (http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/). It works fine on Yii2.

Answer (score 0):

```
->setSize(300)
```

increase that to a larger figure like 500 or 1000